# Show/Hide columns dynamically with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I would like to display option column based on access.computer and books column should display if access is student and teacher and system column should display if access is security.

```
data() {
   return {
     options: ['computer, 'books', 'system'],
     access: ['Student, 'Teacher', 'Security'],

  };
},

<template>
 <tbody >
   <tr>
    <td v-for="(item, index) in access" :key="index">{{item}}></td>
  </tr>
<table >
  <tr >
  <th class=v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
    {{option}} </th> 
     </tr>
  </table>
 </tbody>
</template>
```

Comment: could you show more codes,seem to be incomplete

Comment: instead of have two array in data,maybe you need an strong type whose properties contain option and access with which we can loop.

Comment: I added more codes.I would need to use two array

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear when you ask something. Try this

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
     return {
       options: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Computer' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Books' },
        { id: 3, name: 'System' }
       ],
       access: [
        { name: 'Student', options: [1, 2] },
        { name: 'Teacher', options: [1, 2] },
        { name: 'Security', options: [3] },
       ],
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(access, index) in access" :key="index">{{ access.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="access in access">
        <span v-for="option in access.options" :key="access + option">{{ options.find(tempOpt => tempOpt.id === option).name }}&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```